# XSD use xs:group elements that are not in particular order

Tags: xml, xsd

I have following xml structure

```
<library>
  <propertySet>
    <SUPorganisationId></SUPorganisationId>
    <SUPdataCategory></SUPdataCategory>
    <SUPguId></SUPguId>
    <LIBuserNotice></LIBuserNotice>
  </propertySet>
</library>
```

Properties inside the **propertySet** can be appear once (minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1") and could be any order. When I creating XSD I want to group some of the properties (prefix with SUP) for further using. So I have comeup with following xsd segments.

```
<xs:element name="propertySet">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:group ref="CORproperties"/>
      <xs:element name="LIBuserNotice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="propertySet">

<xs:group name="CORproperties">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="SUPorganisationId" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="SUPdataCategory" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="SUPguId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:group>
```

With this xsd I am getting errors saying that usage of **xs:all** is incorrect. I have forced to use **xs:all** because of there is no order of appearing properties. But it works fine if I use **xs:sequence**. Can anybody please direct me to the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an `<xs:extension>` to do that. If you refactor your schema that way, it will work properly:

**Warning: it is only available in XSD 1.1. In XSD 1.0, it is not allowed.**

```
<xs:element name="propertySet">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="CORProperties">
             <xs:all>
                 <xs:element name="LIBuserNotice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
             </xs:all>
         </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="CORProperties">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="SUPorganisationId" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="SUPdataCategory" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="SUPguId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: As far as I know, content organized by `extension` has order between the elements of `super` and `sub`'s , is there any change in xsd 1.1?

Comment: @potame Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your complexContent solution but it seems complexContent is not with xs:all.  I'am getting following error

Exception: cos-all-limited.1.2: An all model group must appear in a particle with {min occurs} = {max occurs} = 1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the {content type} of a complex type definition.  Its works fine with xs:sequence but I cannot use it because I want to ignore the order.

Comment: For me it just works fine (order is ignored); have you checked you're allowed to use XSD v1.1 - and have set your schema version to 1.1? Otherwise by default the schema version is "1.0" and the raised exception is the one I get for this particular version.

Comment: Thank you very much that was another issue cause this error. This is what exactly I needed. You made me my day. thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

From the annotation of `xs:all`, we see it can't have group:

```
<all
   id = ID
   maxOccurs = 1 : 1
   minOccurs = (0 | 1) : 1
   {any attributes with non-schema namespace . . .}>
   Content: (annotation?, element*)
</all>
```

#### Workaround one: change group to complexType

Of course, this will change the structure of your xml, but this way is more readable than option two.

#### Workaround two: accept duplicates

```
<xs:element name="propertySet">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:group ref="CORproperties"/>
            <xs:element name="LIBuserNotice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:group name="CORproperties">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="SUPorganisationId" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="SUPdataCategory" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="SUPguId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:group>
```

More:

- [all/sequence/choice in xsd](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/xsd-tutorial.html#difference-between-xsall-xssequence-xschoice)

Comment: Thanks Tony. But  If I use  choice only one property element is allowed inside propertySet which is not in this case.

Comment: @PrabuddaSriRahal make your choice `maxOccurs` unbounded can make it appear many times, of course, it may have duplicate one. Can't this meet your need?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can not have duplicates either